# Ubuntu Software Updater cannot find repository information. Check your internet connection

Tags: update-manager, repository

I cannot find what is causing the problem. Any tips on how to go about diagnosing what is wrong? Also, updating takes too long. It just keeps on waiting for headers.

Comment: first, check internet. and then check proxy. and reset Software Center/Edit/Software sources/Download from: as Select best server.

Comment: I did, multiple times. But still no improvement.

Comment: same problem here.